# Strange behaviour with sending strings C# sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a client server application with `Sockets`. Its not optimized yet but that's not the problem. Whenever I send a `string` like "Test" the other side receives "T\0\0\0" So only the first letter of the `string` and the rest of the array, where is save it in,  filled with 0's. I tried changing all kind of values but cant seem to figure out why it does that. The strange thing is, before I send the string its still the entire `string` but as soon as its received its only the first letter. Can someone help me?

Sending

```
public void sendData(Socket sendingSocket, String message)
{
    if (sendingSocket == m_workerSocket[0])
    {
        byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        m_workerSocket[1].Send(byData);

    }
}
```

Receiving

```
public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    try
    {
        SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
        int iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
        char[] chars = new char[iRx + 15]; //Added this to force the array length for test purposes
         Decoder d = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
        //int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        String szData = new String(chars);

        Console.WriteLine(szData);
}
```

EDIT =============================
At the sending part if I brake point

```
m_workerSocket[1].Send(byData);
```

byData contains the entire string. So it has have something to do with the receiving end but I dont know what

Comment: What is the value of `iRx` ? If it is 1 then you read only the first letter

Comment: Both `iRx` and `charLen` are giving you an indication of *how many bytes/chars have been received*. What *value* do they have? I'm guessing 1. I'm guessing also (you haven't said) that you're talking about *TCP*, rather than, for instance, *UDP* (both use sockets). In that case, all that the transport gives you is "a stream of bytes". If you want *messaging*, it's up to you to implement that, or you should move to a higher level abstraction that implements that for you. There's no guarantee that calls of `Send` on one side are matched 1-1 with calls to `Receive` at the other.

Comment: iRx and charLen are both 16 (because i forced them to be larger for test purposes). I know there is no guarantee they will be the same at send and receive but thats not yet a problem becouse of the interval that it sends and receives.

Comment: What do you mean you "forced them"? - `iRx` is whatever `EndReceive` tells you it is. We're asking you what that value is. I.e. when you set a breakpoint on the `chars` declaration line in `OnDataReceived`, what *actual* value do you see in that variable?

Comment: Because i Typed iRx + 15 to see if that was the problem. If I breakpoint the char declaration line its an array with 16 deep with all vallues 0\ after the d.GetChar code its filled with on place 0[0 'T\'] and all other spaces with [0 '0\']

Comment: Why do you use Encoding.Ascii when sending and Encoding.UTF8 when receiving? Furthermore, you may get the string from Encoding.Ascii.GetString.

Comment: Thnx for the feedback about the encoding. Only it didnt fix it :(. When I do this: String test= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(theSockId.dataBuffer); and breakpoint it. test is: T\0\0\0\ So still only the first letter

Comment: "If I breakpoint the char declaration line its an array with 16" if you mean this line: `char[] chars = new char[iRx + 15];` then clearly you receive only 1 byte

Comment: Seems like it, dont know why.

Comment: have you tried just reading manually more bytes than `iRx` allows you? like this: `int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, 3, chars, 0);
` What output do you get then?

Comment: Still only get the first letter. The rest is still 0\

Comment: what is the size of `theSockId.dataBuffer` ?

Comment: the size is 3 or iRx if i use that. Depends on the char[] size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129448/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-zeepblok).